# How do I install libsvm in a conda environment so that I can import svm in anaconda?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, anaconda, libsvm, conda

I have tried installing libsvm using conda as well as pip commands. pip commands are not installing libsvm for conda environment and  when I install it for conda environment using the command - 'conda install -c conda-forge libsvm=3.21' (recommended on various sites) I'm still not able to import svm in my program. 
It shows the error - 'ImportError: No module named svm'

[In conda list libsvm is shown as follows
maybe it has to do something with vc9_1 build instead py27_0/py27_1/py27_2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZozm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZozm.png)

P.S. I'm using python 2.7

Comment: libsvm is a C library, not a Python package, and so you won't be able to import it this way from Python. Is there a particular Python wrapper to libsvm that you're interested in using?

Comment: I want to implement SVM Classifier, as the code i'm refering has imported svm and used all it's functions in python only.

Comment: If you want to do SVM in Python, you might try scikit-learn's SVM classifier, which wraps libsvm: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Comment: @jakevdp I want to use libsvm as my team is using that library and in their system it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: OK – but again libsvm is a C library, not a Python package. If you want to use libsvm from Python, you'll need some Python package or script that wraps the libsvm C interface. If someone is telling you to "import svm", that's referring to a particular Python package or module that you need to install, and you should ask your team what that Python package is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libsvm package from conda-forge channel provides only the shared library, and not the python bindings. If you want both, I'd suggest you do the following:

```
conda remove libsvm
conda install pip
```

Visit http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs and download the latest version of libsvm for your version of python and system architecture:

```
pip install /path/to/downloaded/libsvm-3.21-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

This wheel package contains the following files:

```
libsvm-3.21.data/data/Lib/site-packages/libsvm.dll
libsvm-3.21.data/data/Lib/site-packages/svm.py
libsvm-3.21.data/data/Lib/site-packages/svmutil.py
libsvm-3.21.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
libsvm-3.21.dist-info/metadata.json
libsvm-3.21.dist-info/top_level.txt
libsvm-3.21.dist-info/WHEEL
libsvm-3.21.dist-info/METADATA
libsvm-3.21.dist-info/RECORD
```

Comment: pip install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/tuoh5y4k/libsvm-3.21-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
this command throws:

HTTP error 404 while getting http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/tuoh5y4k/libsvm-3.21-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: @amighty I have updated the answer. Download the package manually via browser and then pip install it locally. The website probably blocks programmatic download of artifacts by blocking certain user-agents in the HTTP headers.